# LogNMagento library

Tags: ios, objective-c, magento, afnetworking

Hi I'm trying to understand how [LogNMagento](https://github.com/lognllc/LogNMagento) library works. I downloaded it, then I re-add this [AfNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/5d341aa8545c5e62632ef0bfbbd21ee6ae685cfc) so I can run the app on the simulator. When I run the example app it doesn't go: it crashes here:

```
SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(self.networkReachability, AFNetworkReachabilityCallback, &context);
```

Exactly in the `AFHTTPClient.m`, not sure about what it's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge, There are two things which will be the cause of crash.:-

1) First thing, if you have included the framework, but not add #import  then it will crash.
Also as per the documentation. This method requires the SystemConfiguration framework. Add it in the active target’s “Link Binary With Library” build phase, and add #import to the header prefix of the project (Prefix.pch)

2) Second thing,  it seems to crash if your baseURL contains an empty string when dealing with requests for unknown URL structures - e.g. fetching an image from a URL specified in the response of a HTTP request.